# GCC -M dependency generation issue

Tags: gcc, dependencies

According to [GNU's documentation](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Preprocessor-Options.html#Preprocessor-Options)

> If there are many included files then the rule is split into several lines using `\`-newline.

After running the following command, why is the output from gcc -M not as expected?
How do I ensure that each dependency appears on a separate line? Thanks for your help in advance.

```
gcc -Iinc/ -Isrc/ -M -MM src/BitSet.c

BitSet.o: src/BitSet.c \
 inc/BitSet.h inc/StdDefs.h
```

I am using GCC 4.5.2 (MinGW) on Windows.

Comment: The output you show is consistent with the documentation you quote, so not sure what to do with your first question. For the second one: why do you want that?

Comment: Thanks for the quick edit/reply. If you notice there are two .h files in one line "inc/Library/BitManipulation/BitSet.h" AND "inc/StdDefs.h". I am using GCC's dependency generation to write a rake-based build tool for my project. My intention is to re-compile a source file if any of its dependencies have changed.

Comment: How is having more than one header on the same line a problem for that?

Comment: It saves me from adding parsing logic if the dependencies are all located on separate lines. I know it's no biggie but I am more curious as to why gcc is behaving this way. It seems to work fine for most other files i.e. it lists every dependency on a new line as stated in the documentation.

Comment: It behaves that way because `make` handles dependencies that way. As I said, the output is consistent with the documentation. I don't see why they would add an option to put one header per line when `make` handles the current format.

Comment: @thegreendroid: are you parsing makefiles? Why

Comment: @Mat I see, I misinterpreted the documentation because I am not familiar with make. I am basically after a tool that'll give me all the dependencies for a given source file and I decided to use gcc for that instead of writing my own.

Comment: @sehe I am parsing the output from the gcc -M option to get a list of dependencies for a 'c' file so that my rake-based tool can re-compile if any of those dependencies change.

Comment: @thegreendroid: parsing the generated make rule is going to be much easier than correctly parsing `C` code, so I'd go with that if I were you.

Comment: @Mat I figured as much, I'll stick to it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You came to expect the wrong thing.

> If there are many included files then the rule is split into
>   several lines using \ -newline.

The rule is split if it is longer than a certain length. Nowhere does the documentation say that the rule will be split after each token.

I.e., fault in the expected output, not in the observed output.

Regarding your comment (building a build tool of your own that uses `gcc -M` output for its dependency tracking)... the output of `gcc -M` is meant to be parsed by `make`, using `make`'s parsing rules. If you want to use the output yourself, you will have to follow the same parsing rules - which aren't that difficult to begin with.

Comment: Thank you, I knew I was missing something from that line in the documentation. My unfamiliarity with `make` led me to thinking it was a bug in GCC :)

Comment: @thegreendroid: IMHO, you shouldn't attempt to create your own build tool if you are not familiar with `make`. One, `make` might be (and probably is) all you need. Two, if `make` doesn't fit the bill, you should be aware of why and where, so your custom build tool actually is an *improvement* over `make`, and not just an inferior NIH remake of it.

Comment: I am actually using `rake` and I am in love with it now. I never learnt `make` but I don't think I'll ever need to because rake is just so much better and has the full power of ruby behind it :)

Comment: @thegreendroid: I have no problem with anyone using rake. But the statement "I never learnt make but I don't think I'll ever need to because rake is just so much better" has a serious flaw in it that should be blatantly obvious. Nevermind, have fun.

Comment: I see your point, I'll rephrase that to "I'll learn `make` when I work on a project that is heavily dependent on it". For now, `rake` seems to cut the mustard just fine. Thanks for your help :)